# Prestashop How update Cart when change order in BackOffice

Tags: cart, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop, how can'i update Cart customer when i change order in BackOffice please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Menu Customers -> Carts

Good luck.

Comment: Hello
I change in order view.
I like when i change in order détails the Cart change automatique 
Thank's